# How does Java compare a Key if it's a File Object?

Tags: java, algorithm, api

Assume I have a HashMap, which stores actual File Objects as the key and the value being it's last modified date.

```
HashMap<File, Long> hashMap = new HashMap<File, Long>();
```

If the File (test.log) exists in my HashMap (I've added it), but the file (test.log) is modified or changed later; when I issue a replace, will it find the existing matching Object, or will the STATE change of the File, which will change the nature of the Object. Thus I will be indirectly adding a new Key,Value Pair.

```
hashMap.replace(file, newModifiedTime);
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the code of File.equals()?

Comment: No but based on the answers I clearly should have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [javadoc equal's description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Tests this abstract pathname for equality with the given object. Returns true if and only if the argument is not null and is an abstract pathname that denotes the same file or directory as this abstract pathname. Whether or not two abstract pathnames are equal depends upon the underlying system.

Answer (score 1):

`File`'s `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` test for the name of the file, so your keys are "safe".

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) says so.

Note: if you use JDK 7 or later, do yourself a favor: drop `File`, use `Files`/`Path`.

Note 2: please note that if you are in directory `/foo`, `new File("bar")` and `new File("/foo/bar")` are **not the same**. If you want to ensure that the file name is "complete", use `.getCanonicalFile()`.

But again, do yourself a favor and use `Files`. It is orders of magnitude better.

Answer (score 0):

What is stored has a Key is the Hashing of the file. This won't actually mean that the full object gets hashed. Only the Path is used to generate the File object's hash.

When storing an object as a Key to an hash table. It will internally call `.hashCode()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#hashCode()

From the docs.

> Computes a hash code for this abstract pathname. Because equality of
>   abstract pathnames is inherently system-dependent, so is the
>   computation of their hash codes. On UNIX systems, the hash code of an
>   abstract pathname is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code of its
>   pathname string and the decimal value 1234321. On Microsoft Windows
>   systems, the hash code is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code
>   of its pathname string converted to lower case and the decimal value
>   1234321. Locale is not taken into account on lowercasing the pathname string.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` uses the `hashCode()` method of its keys.  And `File.hashCode()` does this, according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#hashCode%28%29):

> Computes a hash code for this abstract pathname. Because equality of
>   abstract pathnames is inherently system-dependent, so is the
>   computation of their hash codes. On UNIX systems, the hash code of an
>   abstract pathname is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code of its
>   pathname string and the decimal value 1234321. On Microsoft Windows
>   systems, the hash code is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code
>   of its pathname string converted to lower case and the decimal value
>   1234321. Locale is not taken into account on lowercasing the pathname string.

In short, the hash is computed based on the pathname, not the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` uses `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods of class instances of which is used as keys, i.e. `File` in your case. In case of File it compares abstract paths by delegating the functionality to concrete file system wrapper.

If you want to change this behavior you probably should use `TreeMap` and implement your own custom comparator that compares the file content, last modification date etc.